# How do I get rid of the -16 when doing horizontal layout to the edge of the superview in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

When you try to layout a view to the edge of its super view in Xcode 6 storyboards the constraint that is generated has a constant of -16. Why is this, and how can I make it back to 0?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The -16 is because the constraint is set against the `Superview.trailing/leading Margin` not the edge of the superview. You can fix this by selecting the constraint and in the info in the top right select the drop down for the superview item and toggle the `relative to margin` to off.[image]