# iOS7 View offset: both top and right

Tags: ios7, autolayout, constraints, offset

the APP displays in normal, but after adding constraints with no error:

iOS8, it works fine in any device.

iOS7, all the things, such as buttons, labels and views, about 10px offset from the top and right, all the things run to bottom and left about 10px.

if try to code the app with no constraints, and choose a fixed simulated size, for example "iPhone-4inch", and select the same device to run the simulator, it works fine both with iOS7 and iOS8.

BTW, I'm coding with swift. Thanks.

Comment: Anybody can help? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about constraints margin things, finally found the answer here
[How do I get rid of the -16 when doing horizontal layout to the edge of the superview in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768570/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-16-when-doing-horizontal-layout-to-the-edge-of-the-supe)